# Insert multiple records with a single query using JPA methods

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a spring boot application where I want to insert multiple records using a single DB query:-

```
public void addEvents() {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Data values(1,'Data 1'), (2,'Data 2'),(3,'Data 3')";
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

**Entity Class:-**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Data {
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Data(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Data(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Data() {
    }
}
```

Here Data is an Entity which I am inserting. I need to insert more than 10000 rows in my DB within secs. So firing individual DB calls is too costly. Therefore I had used a single query for this purpose. This query is a native query. Can anyone please tell me if JPA provides an out of the box API to insert multiple entities in a single DB cl?

Comment: Can you add your entity class here?

Comment: @ShaunakPatel -  Added Please check now

Comment: I suggest you should have batch job to handle this case. Run the batch job to insert these many records during the time when the server is not busy (time at which user traffic is less)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *saveAll* method of spring-data to have bulk insert. Here is a code snippet,

```
List<Data> dataList = <10000 records> //You need to prepare batch of 10000

dataRepository.saveAll(dataList) //Spring boot will handle batches automatically.
```

Add following properties in `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
```

You can see generated query using `spring.jpa.show-sql`

Update:
Add following dependency in your pom.xml,

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.integralblue</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Above dependency will show in log if batch is happening or not.

Comment: Here I can see that 1000 sql queries are being fired.

Comment: The below 4 queries are getting fired when I am trying to insert 2 Data records:-


Hibernate: select data0_.id as id1_0_0_, data0_.name as name2_0_0_ from data data0_ where data0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: select data0_.id as id1_0_0_, data0_.name as name2_0_0_ from data data0_ where data0_.id=?
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into data (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into data (name, id) values (?, ?)

Comment: can you add your code in public repository? I would like to see.

Comment: U can check the code here -m https://github.com/PracticeOrganization09/Sample-Code

Comment: @Sunny, batch is already happening but it was not visible into the logs. I have updated my answer to show behavior with batch enable.